# Enable Recent files icon in the sidebar of File explorer

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade, nautilus, icons

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.2 LTS.

This is a sample image of file explorer before upgrade. As you can see there is an icon for recently used files in the sidebar.

[image: File Explorer in Ubuntu 15.10]

Now have a look at file explorer after upgrade. As you can see the option for recent files is gone.

[image: File Explorer in Ubuntu 15.10]

How can I enable this option in Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS?

---

EDIT: @Ravexina. This is what I got after typing `recent:///` in nautilus address bar. The recent folder is opening but it is not showing any of the recently opened files.

[image: nautilus:///]

Comment: I've got it in my 16.04... did you change anything?

Comment: @Ravexina I did not change anything. I simply used 'sudo do-release-upgrade' command to upgrade to the latest LTS version.

Comment: Close nautilus, run: `mv .config/nautilus/ .config/nautilus-bk`, run nautilus see if anything changed.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr .local/share/recently-used.xbel `

Comment: Also in nautilus press ctrl+l in address bar type `recent:///` press enter;  does it show recent files?

Comment: @Ravexina I don't have that `recent` thing and have never had...just like the OP

Comment: @George I've got it, in both my minimal installation and also full installation in VM.

Comment: @Ravexina another string stuff is gedit won't show recent file too

Comment: @Ravexina This is the output of `lsattr .local/share/recently-used.xbel` command: `-------------e-- .local/share/recently-used.xbel`

Comment: What about typing `recent:///` in nautilus address bar.

Comment: @George Mine works even in `gedit`, however it's not up to date, version is: `3.14.1`. but my minimal installation is up to date `3.14.3` and I've got it.

Comment: @Ravexina Please see my edited question for the command `recent:///`

Comment: @RD017 just saw it, working around it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to "System Settings" and choose "Security and Privacy" go to "files & applications" tab and turn "Record file and application usage" on.

[image]

---

As an alternative in nautilus (file manager), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> so you can enter "Addresss/Path", then type in: `recent:///` and press enter. It should show the recent files.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to bookmark this into your nautilus sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Can I move it above Home icon?

Comment: See my update should work for you ...

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu LTS 22.04:
go to "Parameters", "Privacy", and then "File history and bin" and click to activate the option "File history" (here Ubuntu in French):
[image]